# how to get prediction from trained random forest model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, random-forest

i have a dataset with two columns user posts (posts) and personality type (type) , i need personality type according to posts using this dataset so i used random forest regression for prediction 
here is my code:-

```
df = pd.read_csv('personality_types.csv')

count_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(decode_error='ignore')
X = count_vectorizer.fit_transform(df['posts'])
y = df['type'].values

Xtrain, Xtest, Ytrain, Ytest = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.33)

random_forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=100)
random_forest.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain)
Y_prediction = random_forest.predict(Xtest)
```

accuracy:

```
random_forest.score(Xtrain, Ytrain)
acc_random_forest = round(random_forest.score(Xtrain, Ytrain) * 100, 2)
print(round(acc_random_forest,2,), "%")

100%
```

now i want to get prediction from a custom text how can i achive that ?
how can i get personality type of a post separately using this model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a new column in the same dataset which is df . Name it as custom_text or user_text or anything else.Take the input store it in that column so that all the rows of that column contains the same values

```
custom_text = input("Enter Text")
custom_text = count_vectorizer.transform(df['custom_text'])
value_predicted = random_forest.predict(custom_text)
print(value_predicted[0])
```

as all values of value_predicted contains the same value

Answer (score 0):

If there's a `df` with custom text in the same format as the `posts`, you can do the following:

```
custom_text = count_vectorizer.transform(df['custom_text'])
value_predicted = random_forest.predict(custom_text)
```

`value_predicted` contains the results. Of course, `count_vectorizer` and `random_forest` should be trained models from your example.

Also, there's probably a typo in your example, you shoul check performance on the test, not the train:

```
random_forest.score()
acc_random_forest = round(random_forest.score(Xtest, Ytest) * 100, 2)
print(round(acc_random_forest,2,), "%")
Out:
<Some score>
```

100% accuracy score looks like an [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting).

Comment: tried it! got this ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 14542 and input n_features is 286

Comment: Looks like that `count_vectorizer` was changed somewhere. Could it be accidentally replaced by a new version (for example, you do `.fit_transform` on a new data)?

Comment: Also, if there's such a problem, you may edit your question and add this problem. If you work in `jupyter notebook`, you can try to restart it and run from top to bottom carefully - sometimes this error just disappears because usually it's an error of a wrong state.